# Getting the URL where the data is

Tags: python, web-scraping

So I'm trying to get some data from this site. https://www.futbin.com/20/player/24255/iago-aspas . 
As you can see, there are two types of graphs there, one showing the price of the card by day (Daily Graph), and the other one showing the price by each hour the last 3 days (Hourly Graph).

Now, I don't have any type of problem getting the data from the Daily Graph, I'm doing it like this.

```
r = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/20/playerGraph?type=daily_graph&year=20&player={0}'.format(id))
```

I'm using the ID from the player to get the data and this is what I get.

[Data from Daily Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/626qd.png)

But now, I'm not sure on how to get the data from the "Hourly Graph".

Comment: Looking in chrome's network monitor, it looks like you just need to set `type` in that URL to `today` instead of `daily_graph`.

Answer (score 1):

- Open developer tools in the browser before clicking on "Hourly Graph" (usually the hotkey is F12)
- select Network tab in developer tools. Optionally clear the history
- click "Hourly Graph". You'll see a new request with a URL like this:
  `https://www.futbin.com/20/playerGraph?type=today&year=20&player=192629&set_id=`

Same strategy works for most other websites

Comment: What I ended up doing was this: https://www.futbin.com/20/playerGraph?type=daily_graph&type=yesterday&year=20&player={0} .But now I have the problem since there are different types of cards of certain players, so passing the ID of the player is not an option.